# on checkbox check transfer data between tables accordingly

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I have 2 tables one has Hobby_id and Hobby_name the other table has Id and selected_hobby field .I want to make a drop down with check box's bind with table 1 data. When i check the check box that value should get inserted in table number 2,And when i uncheck it again ,It gets removed from that table.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Checked` Properte from the checkbox with if statement to solve your problem like below code

```
if (checkBox1.Checked){
    //do anything you want from here 
    }
else{
    //else you want 
    }
```

Comment: can u plz give me some example...how can i store tempory data in 2nd table